# Edit the (automatic) HTML layout of nav menus

Tags: menus

I registered my menu in functions.php, called it from header.php and set it all up in the Appearances > Menus backend. The problem is, I need to manually insert a div surrounding `<ul class="sub-menu"> ... </ul>` where my drop-down menu is.

There is no way around it like adding the div's class to the ul etc., as in order for it's drop-down functionality to work it must be inserted in that way, so that my code can be:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>
        <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Is there any easy way to get that `<div class="dropdown">` and `</div>` part in easily? Or would the only way be by writing a script?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: The question was actually how to wrap the submenus, not the whole menu. Here are 2 options:

using jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// run this before the script that sets up the dropdowns:
jQuery(document.ready(function($){
    $('.sub-menu').wrap('<div class="dropdown"></div>');
})

</script>
```

using PHP 5.3+ (slightly more complex option, but thought i'd post it):

```
<?php
$dom = DOMDocument::loadHTML(wp_nav_menu(array(
    'menu' => 'main', // change this to your theme location
    'echo' => false,
)));

// Find all uls
$uls = $dom->getElementsByTagName('ul');

// Find & wrap each sub menu
foreach ($uls AS $ul) 
{
    if ($ul->getAttribute('class') == 'sub-menu')
    {
        // create the dropdown wrapper div
        $wrapper = $dom->createElement('div');
        $wrapper->setAttribute('class', 'dropdown');

        // Replace ul with this wrapper div
        $ul->parentNode->replaceChild($wrapper, $ul);

        // Append this ul to wrapper div
        $wrapper->appendChild($ul);
    }
}
echo $dom->saveHTML($dom->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0));

?>
```

// OLD ANSWER:

Check out the `container_class` option of `wp_nav_menu()`: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Your menu's `ul` will automatically be wrapped in a div; you can set the class of the div using that option:

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme_location' => 'my_location', // change this to your theme location
    'container_class' => 'dropdown',
));
?>
```

Comment: Hey Jessica. Thank you for the answer. I'm actually using `container_class` at the moment to wrap the entire menu in a div, but what I need to do here is wrap just the sub-menu `<ul>` part from above in a div.

Comment: @brycead Oh, missed that! In that case, there are a couple ways I can think of to accomplish this. Do you know if your theme uses jQuery? If not, do you know if you're running php 5.3?

Comment: The theme's one I'm building at the moment, and yeah the whole dropdown menu bit will ideally be using jQuery. I'm building it using the Gumby Framework (http://gumbyframework.com) and I suppose for the dropdown jQuery to work the dropdown part of the menu needs to be wrapped in that div. Yep php 5.3+

Comment: @brycead Cool, I updated my answer with some options you could use.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm missing something, but for what I understand what you need is as simple as the following:

```
<div class="dropdown">
<div class="whatever">
<?php
wp_nav_menu(array(
'theme_location' => 'my_location', // change this to your theme location
'container_class' => 'dropdown',
));
?>
</div>
</div>
```

but then again, not sure if I'm understanding your question